# Dynamodb ondemand cost and scaling during hot partition(adaptive scaling)

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I can understand the provisioned DB cost but there are few questions regd on-demand nodes.

does OnDemand pricing only considers the sum of WRU used by each partition or the overall WRU for the table based on the usage pattern which will be shared by each partition.

when there is a hot partition, does OnDemand increase WRU only for that partition or increases the overall WRU of the table.

does adaptive capacity work with OnDemand DB

ex: 
OnDemand DB with 10 partitions and current peak at 1000WRU.
if 2 hot partitions require more than 300WRU will it use from adaptive capacity or increase the overall WRU to 3000WRU resulting in high cost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a DynamoDB insider, so I can only answer from what I understand from their documentation.

In on-demand pricing (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html#HowItWorks.OnDemand) you pay exactly by the number and size of your requests. If you make one million requests, you will pay the same whether these requests were to a million different partitions, or they all went to the same partition.

You might wonder, then, why there was such an issue of load imbalance pricing in **provisioned**-capacity pricing - or at least why is the Web full of stories of such an issue. There should never have been such an issue, but in the past there was. But since recently, this isn't an issue any more. Here is the story:

In the provisioned pricing page, Amazon claims that if you reserve 1000 WCU, you should be able to use this number of write units that you paid for, per second, and if you try to use more, you'll be throttled. There is no mention or warning of imbalanced loads or hot partitions... But people discovered that this wasn't quite true - Amazon had a **bug** in their throttling code: The usage counting wasn't done across the entire cluster. Instead, if your data was spread over 10 nodes, your reservation of 1000 was evenly split among them, so each of the 10 nodes would start to throttle you after 100 (1000/10) requests per second. This split worked well for well-balanced loads, but with hot partitions, it didn't work well. People were paying for a reservation of 1000 but when they measured how much they were getting, they saw throttling after just 800 (for example) requests per second. Amazon acknowledge this was a bug, and fixed it with their "adaptive capacity" technique where each of the nodes picks a different throttling limit, modified until the user's total usage approaches what he had paid for. This technique is explained in this excellent official talk
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvBR71D0nAQ - see time 19:38. Until very recently this "adaptive capacity" was a very blunt instrument, which only worked well if your workload doesn't change quickly, but since then, this issue was fixed too - as described in
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-amazon-dynamodb-adaptive-capacity-accommodates-uneven-data-access-patterns-or-why-what-you-know-about-dynamodb-might-be-outdated/